# How to build XeTeX and dvipdfmx from source (TexLive 2020)

Tags: xetex, texlive, dvipdfmx

What would be the most minimalistic way to build xetex+dvipdfmx from source?

My current problem is that I cannot reliably disabling building all other (unncessary?) texlive programs, so `--disable-all-pkgs` doesn't seem to work. Ideally, I'd get something as minimal as https://github.com/TeX-Live/xetex/tree/master/source/texk/web2c + https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source/tree/master/texk/dvipdfm-x.

Any advice how to make this build more compact?

Thanks!

I consulted http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/pst/texlive.html and https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlbuild.html#Build-one-engine.
When I try `cd texlive-20200406-source/texlive-build/texk/web2c && make xetex` instead of `make`, it fails and cannot find the `xetex` target. I don't understand well how to build only some programs with a standard, out-of-tree build. Maybe something's wrong about configure arguments.

```
# does not include yet final steps with tlpd and texmf

wget ftp://tug.org/texlive/historic/2020/texlive-20200406-source.tar.xz 
tar -xf texlive-20200406-source.tar.xz

MAKEFLAGS=-j20

PREFIX=$PWD/prefix
mkdir -p $PREFIX
CACHE=$PWD/config.cache

pushd texlive-20200406-source

mkdir -p texlive-build
pushd texlive-build

../configure                                        \
  --cache-file=$CACHE                            \
  --prefix=$PREFIX                                \
  --disable-dvisvgm                               \
  --disable-luatex                                \
  --disable-luajittex                             \
  --disable-luahbtex                              \
  --disable-luajithbtex                           \
  --disable-mflua                                 \
  --disable-mfluajit                              \
  --disable-biber                              \
  --disable-etex                                   \
  --disable-detex                              \
  --disable-dvi2tty                                \
  --disable-dvipng                                 \
  --disable-dvisvgm                                \
  --disable-lcdf-typetools                         \
  --disable-ps2eps                                 \
  --disable-psutils                                \
  --disable-t1utils                                \
  --disable-texinfo                                \
  --disable-xindy                              \
  --disable-all-pkgs                              \
  --disable-multiplatform                         \
  --enable-static                                 \
  --disable-shared                                \
  --enable-web2c                                  \
  --enable-xetex                                  \
  --enable-dvipdfm-x                                \
  --without-x                                     \
  --without-system-cairo                          \
  --without-system-gmp                            \
  --without-system-graphite2                      \
  --without-system-harfbuzz                       \
  --without-system-libgs                          \
  --without-system-libpaper                       \
  --without-system-mpfr                           \
  --without-system-pixman                         \
  --without-system-poppler                        \
  --without-system-xpdf                           \
  --without-system-icu                               \
  --without-system-fontconfig                        \
  --without-system-freetype2                         \
  --without-system-libpng                            \
  --without-system-zlib                              \
  --with-banner-add=" - BLFS"

make $MAKEFLAGS
make $MAKEFLAGS install
```

```
ls prefix/bin
aleph           cweave    ebb        inimf         mf-nowin  odvitype  ovf2ovp   pdvitype  ptex       teckit_compile  updvitype  weave
bibtex          dvicopy   eptex      initex        mfplain   ofm2opl   ovp2ovf   pktogf    ptftopl    tex             upmpost    wofm2opl
ctangle         dvipdfm   euptex     kpseaccess    mft       omfonts   patgen    pktype    r-mpost    tftopl          uppltotf   wopl2ofm
ctie            dvipdfmx  extractbb  kpsereadlink  mkocp     opl2ofm   pbibtex   pltotf    r-pmpost   tie             uptex      wovf2ovp
ctwill          dvipdft   gftodvi    kpsestat      mkofm     otangle   pdftex    pmpost    r-upmpost  ttf2afm         uptftopl   wovp2ovf
ctwill-refsort  dvitomp   gftopk     kpsewhich     mpost     otp2ocp   pdftosrc  pooltype  synctex    upbibtex        vftovp     xdvipdfmx
ctwill-twinx    dvitype   gftype     mf            odvicopy  outocp    pdvitomp  ppltotf   tangle     updvitomp       vptovf     xetex

ls prefix/lib
libkpathsea.a  libkpathsea.la  libptexenc.a  libptexenc.la  libsynctex.a  pkgconfig
```

When building just with `--disable-all-pkgs`:

```
../configure                                        \
  --cache-file=$CACHE                            \
  --prefix=$PREFIX                                \
  --enable-static                               \
  --disable-shared                              \
  --disable-multiplatform                         \
  --disable-native-texlive-build                  \
  --disable-all-pkgs                              \
  --without-x                                     \
  --without-system-cairo                          \
  --without-system-gmp                            \
  --without-system-graphite2                      \
  --without-system-harfbuzz                       \
  --without-system-libgs                          \
  --without-system-libpaper                       \
  --without-system-mpfr                           \
  --without-system-pixman                         \
  --without-system-poppler                        \
  --without-system-xpdf                           \
  --without-system-icu                               \
  --without-system-fontconfig                        \
  --without-system-freetype2                         \
  --without-system-libpng                            \
  --without-system-zlib                              \
  --with-banner-add=" - BLFS"
```

```
ls prefix
share
```

When building with `--disable-all-pkgs --enable-xetex --enable-dvipdfm-x` (without `--enable-web2c`):

```
../configure                                        \
  --cache-file=$CACHE                            \
  --prefix=$PREFIX                                \
  --enable-static                               \
  --enable-xetex                                  \
  --enable-dvipdfm-x                               \
  --disable-shared                              \
  --disable-multiplatform                         \
  --disable-native-texlive-build                  \
  --disable-all-pkgs                              \
  --disable-dvipng                              \
  --disable-dvisvgm                                 \
  --disable-dvi2tty                                 \
  --disable-luatex                                \
  --disable-luajittex                             \
  --disable-luahbtex                              \
  --disable-luajithbtex                           \
  --disable-mflua                                 \
  --disable-mfluajit                              \
  --disable-etex                                    \
  --disable-detex                               \
  --disable-lcdf-typetools                      \
  --disable-ps2eps                              \
  --disable-psutils                                 \
  --disable-t1utils                                 \
  --disable-texinfo                                 \
  --disable-xindy                               \
  --disable-biber                               \
  --without-x                                     \
  --without-system-cairo                          \
  --without-system-gmp                            \
  --without-system-graphite2                      \
  --without-system-harfbuzz                       \
  --without-system-libgs                          \
  --without-system-libpaper                       \
  --without-system-mpfr                           \
  --without-system-pixman                         \
  --without-system-poppler                        \
  --without-system-xpdf                           \
  --without-system-icu                               \
  --without-system-fontconfig                        \
  --without-system-freetype2                         \
  --without-system-libpng                            \
  --without-system-zlib                              \
  --with-banner-add=" - BLFS"
```

```
ls prefix/bin
dvipdfm  dvipdfmx  dvipdft  ebb  extractbb  kpseaccess  kpsereadlink  kpsestat  kpsewhich  xdvipdfmx
```

**I managed to compile xetex and dvipdfm-x from TexLive**. However, creating a format file fails:

```
TEXLIVE_BASE_URL=http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base.zip
TEXLIVE_INSTALLER_URL=http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz

mkdir -p texlive
echo selected_scheme scheme-basic > texlive/profile.input
echo TEXDIR $PWD/texlive >> texlive/profile.input
echo TEXMFLOCAL $PWD/texlive/texmf-local >> texlive/profile.input
echo TEXMFSYSVAR $PWD/texlive/texmf-var >> texlive/profile.input
echo TEXMFSYSCONFIG $PWD/texlive/texmf-config >> texlive/profile.input
echo TEXMFVAR $PWD/home/texmf-var >> texlive/profile.input

wget $TEXLIVE_INSTALLER_URL
pushd texlive
tar xzvf ../install-tl-unx.tar.gz
./install-tl-*/install-tl -profile profile.input
rm -rf bin readme* tlpkg install* *.html texmf-dist/doc texmf-var/web2c
echo "Done! Please run 'make texlive.lst' now!"
popd

wget $TEXLIVE_BASE_URL
mkdir -p latex_format
pushd latex_format
unzip -o ../base.zip
pushd base
$XELATEX_EXE -ini -etex unpack.ins
$XELATEX_EXE -ini -etex latex.ltx
```

```
Local config file preload.cfg used

=====================================
(base/preload.cfg (base/preload.ltx
kpathsea: Running mktextfm cmex10
mktextfm: No such file or directory
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font \OMX/cmex/m/n/10=cmex10 not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed fon
t not found.
<to be read again>
                   \relax
l.41 ...ame OMX/cmex/m/n/10\endcsname=cmex10\relax
```

Comment: The configure step is necessary before you can do the make. What happens when you try to run `./configure --disable-all-pkgs`? Alternatively, the readme indicates that you could run `./Build` from the TeXlive-xxx-source directory.

Comment: I mainly followed BLFS, so used `./configure` directly (without `Build`), note taken stripping the output binaries must be done manually. When I use `--disable-all-pkgs` only, it indeed does not produce any binary results (updated the original post). I'll now try using `--disable-all-pkgs --enable-xetex --enable-dvipdfm-x` (without `--enable-web2c`).

Comment: Building `--disable-all-pkgs --enable-xetex --enable-dvipdfm-x` (without `--enable-web2c`) does not produce a `xetex` binary: `dvipdfm  dvipdfmx  dvipdft  ebb  extractbb  kpseaccess  kpsereadlink  kpsestat  kpsewhich  xdvipdfmx`

So I guess `--enable-web2c` and manual disabling unnecessary web2c tools is a must :( Any advice?

Comment: Hmm, I downloaded the sources package and tried doing a build following `README.2building` and found that the documentation is at best out of date if not wrong (as in their steps for building `luatex` solo generate an error on the first command and trying to continue from there by creating a `Work` directory and running `../configure --disable-all-pkgs` followed by the `make` command they suggest gives your error. It looks like the documentation is wrong/incomplete.

Comment: My latest attempt: https://gist.github.com/vadimkantorov/501634e4f0c93b2940b43aea071dff03 I managed to build xetex+dvipdfmx, but not yet to build latex format files out of base.zip archive: getting some font TMF files not found errors

Comment: I updated the question with the details about font problems

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're running into now is that you're missing the font files. I think you're going to run into a lot of trial and error steps installing things piecemeal. You'll need to have the font files from [fonts/cm](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cm) and install these in the appropriate directories for a TeX install (there's a reason that most people just do the TeXlive install).

Out of curiosity, what is your goal with this process? I'm thinking it might be easier to prune a full install than to try to build a selective one piecemeal.

Comment: I'm trying to update compiling XeTeX to WebAssembly from https://github.com/lyze/xetex-js and https://github.com/manuels/texlive.js/ in order to use it client-side on simple documents. I found that getting a minimal native build is a useful step before using emscripten

Comment: I also have ftp://tug.org/texlive/historic/2020/texlive-20200406-texmf.tar.xz downloaded, but don't know how to use it for this (I read about fmtutil, but both xetex-js and texlive.js use `./xelatex -ini`...)

Comment: Would you have advice how to google for installing minimal set of fonts? Or at least where they should be installed to? I found a seemingly self-contained set of scripts in MacPorts: https://github.com/macports/macports-ports/tree/master/tex, but still struggle to parse through the install sequence and their DSL

Comment: If I understand https://tug.org/tds/tds.pdf well, I need to now somehow populate a root texmf directory and put there a `fonts` subdirectory prior to making a format file. Is that right? Is there a recipe for doing that? BLFS seems to use `mktexlsr && fmtutil-sys --all && mtxrun --generate` for that. Is there a non-root way to make a suitable texmf root with a minimal set of fonts (e.g. to begin with, English only)? Of course in practice I'd need to have some sort of online package system to download the required packages.

Comment: From what I understood, both xetex-js and texlive.js actually use a native install to make automatic package preparation work. I'm trying the updated code snippet (that uses `install-tl-unx.tar.gz`)  in my original post, but I still get fonts errors. I'm not sure how to make `xelatex -ini` know about the `texlive` directory:

Comment: I think you'll want to open a new question on this—I suspect the two of us are the only ones looking at our current discussion.

Comment: created a new https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/560336/how-to-create-a-latex-format-file-without-an-existing-texlive-install

Comment: Would you know where in the source code does XeTeX sets the file name of the log file to be used? For some reason, my emscripten xetex decides to set empty file name, and so cannot open the log file for  writing. But I can't find where that filename setting is done

Comment: I'm mostly familiar with the original `tex.web` source code so I'm probably not much help. The job name there gets set in the `start_input` procedure if it hasn't been set yet (and if it there's no input name when the log file is first written, it should default to `texput`.

Comment: Thanks! It's very relevant! It seems that in Emscripten build somehow the string references are off, and pack_file_name doesn't then format the joined file path correctly

Comment: I found that somehow Emscripten version of xetex0.c uses str_numbers < 65536 that causes some out-of-bound access ([details](https://github.com/lyze/xetex-js/issues/4#issuecomment-689864076)). How is xetex0.c produced? Via some web2c call after tie call? I wonder how this offset is determined.