# How to create a LaTeX format file without an existing TexLive install

Tags: xetex, texlive

My machine does not have an existing TexLive install. I managed to build a XeTeX binary from sources (steps in [How to build XeTeX and dvipdfmx from source (TexLive 2020)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/560046/how-to-build-xetex-and-dvipdfmx-from-source-texlive-2020))

I am now trying to create format files (complete script that I execute is [here](https://gist.github.com/vadimkantorov/501634e4f0c93b2940b43aea071dff03)). I am getting an error from `xelatex -ini -etex latex.ltx` indicating that it can't locate the fonts. Fonts are present in `./texlive` directory populated by `./install-tl`.

How do I instruct `xetex` binary to look into this directory? (I copied `cp xetex xelatex`).

[@DonHosek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/202780/don-hosek) suggested I create a separate question for this part of debugging. Broader context: I am trying to update outdated [xetex-js](https://github.com/lyze/xetex-js) and [texlive.js](https://github.com/manuels/texlive.js/) to TexLive 2020 in order to create a simple in-browser LaTeX renderer.

```
Local config file preload.cfg used

=====================================
(base/preload.cfg (base/preload.ltx
kpathsea: Running mktextfm cmex10
mktextfm: No such file or directory
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font \OMX/cmex/m/n/10=cmex10 not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed fon
t not found.
<to be read again>
                   \relax
l.41 ...ame OMX/cmex/m/n/10\endcsname=cmex10\relax
```

```
TEXLIVE_BASE_URL=http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base.zip
TEXLIVE_INSTALLER_URL=http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz

# path to my newly built xetex
XELATEX_EXE=$PWD/prefix/bin/xelatex

mkdir -p texlive
echo selected_scheme scheme-basic > texlive/profile.input
echo TEXDIR $PWD/texlive >> texlive/profile.input
echo TEXMFLOCAL $PWD/texlive/texmf-local >> texlive/profile.input
echo TEXMFSYSVAR $PWD/texlive/texmf-var >> texlive/profile.input
echo TEXMFSYSCONFIG $PWD/texlive/texmf-config >> texlive/profile.input
echo TEXMFVAR $PWD/home/texmf-var >> texlive/profile.input

wget $TEXLIVE_INSTALLER_URL
pushd texlive
tar xzvf ../install-tl-unx.tar.gz
./install-tl-*/install-tl -profile profile.input
rm -rf bin readme* tlpkg install* *.html texmf-dist/doc texmf-var/web2c
echo "Done! Please run 'make texlive.lst' now!"
popd

wget $TEXLIVE_BASE_URL

mkdir -p latex_format
pushd latex_format
unzip -o ../base.zip
pushd base
$XELATEX_EXE -ini -etex unpack.ins
$XELATEX_EXE -ini -etex latex.ltx
```

**UPDATE** somehow `kpathsea` cannot find `mktextfm` which is in `$TEXLIVE_SOURCE_DIR/texk/texlive/linked_scripts/texlive`. If I add it to PATH, then `./prefix/bin/kpsewhich` cannot find `mktex.opt` which is in `./texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/mktex.opt`. `./prefix/share/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf` does not know anything about `./texlive`. How do I make sure that `./prefix/bin/kpsewhich` can discover `./texlive` and produce format files?

Comment: I suggest you report your question about the chat where the LaTeX kernel maintainers are discussing, here :  [TeX, LaTeX and Friends](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends)

Comment: You need to ensure that TFMFONTS is set to wherever the tfm fonts are that should be true already with the default texmf.cnf that should have been installed but...

Comment: David, I tried: `export TFMFONTS=$PWD/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm; cd base; $XELATEX_EXE -ini -etex latex.ltx` and it still fails. I checked, `cm` font is indeed inside `texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/cm`

Comment: Oh, it seems that `mktextfm` was not found on disk: `kpathsea: Running mktextfm cmex10; mktextfm: No such file or directory`

Comment: It seems that I need to add to path `texlive-20200406-source/texk/texlive/linked_scripts/texlive/`, correct?

Comment: Okay, I managed to add `mktextfm` to PATH. Now it can't find `mktex.opt` which is in  `texlive/texmf-dist/web2c`: `./prefix/bin/kpsewhich --format=web2c files mktex.opt` prints empty string.

Comment: The problem seems that I have not built/installed any web2c programs. I manually built `xetex` in-tree and simply copied it to the output. If `./prefix/share/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf` is used by the `kpsewhich`, then it cannot find `./texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/mktex.opt`

Comment: `./prefix/share/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf` contains currently useless TEXMFHOME and other vars. My install from `./install-tl` is in `./texlive`. Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: The full script that I executed originally is: https://gist.github.com/vadimkantorov/501634e4f0c93b2940b43aea071dff03. Happy to hear any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add `export TEXMFDIST=$PWD/texlive/texmf-dist`, so that `kpsewhich` can discover the native install as suggested in https://github.com/lyze/xetex-js/issues/4#issuecomment-682257902.

My complete [script](https://gist.github.com/vadimkantorov/501634e4f0c93b2940b43aea071dff03) is for completeness:

````
# http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/pst/texlive.html
# https://www.tug.org/texlive/build.html
# https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlbuild.html#Build-one-engine

export MAKEFLAGS=-j20

TEXLIVE_TEXMF_URL=ftp://tug.org/texlive/historic/2020/texlive-20200406-texmf.tar.xz
TEXLIVE_SOURCE_URL=ftp://tug.org/texlive/historic/2020/texlive-20200406-source.tar.xz
TEXLIVE_TLPDB_URL=ftp://tug.org/texlive/historic/2020/texlive-20200406-tlpdb-full.tar.gz
TEXLIVE_BASE_URL=http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base.zip
TEXLIVE_INSTALLER_URL=http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz
TEXLIVE_SOURCE_DIR=$PWD/texlive-20200406-source

ROOT=$PWD
TEXLIVE=$PWD/texlive
PREFIX=$PWD/prefix
CACHE=$PWD/config.cache
XELATEX_EXE=$PREFIX/bin/xelatex
XETEX_EXE=$PREFIX/bin/xetex
mkdir -p $PREFIX

wget --no-clobber $TEXLIVE_SOURCE_URL
tar -xvf $(basename $TEXLIVE_SOURCE_URL)
cd $TEXLIVE_SOURCE_DIR
mkdir -p texlive-build
cd texlive-build


#  --disable-dvipng                                 \
#  --disable-dvisvgm                            \
#  --disable-dvi2tty                            \
#  --disable-luatex                              \
#  --disable-luajittex                           \
#  --disable-luahbtex                            \
#  --disable-luajithbtex                         \
#  --disable-mflua                               \
#  --disable-mfluajit                            \
#  --disable-etex                               \
#  --disable-detex                              \
#  --disable-lcdf-typetools                         \
#  --disable-ps2eps                                 \
#  --disable-psutils                            \
#  --disable-t1utils                            \
#  --disable-texinfo                            \
#  --disable-xindy                              \
#  --disable-biber                              \

../configure                                    \
  --cache-file=$CACHE                           \
  --prefix=$PREFIX                              \
  --enable-static                               \
  --enable-xetex                                \
  --enable-dvipdfm-x                            \
  --disable-shared                              \
  --disable-multiplatform                       \
  --disable-native-texlive-build                \
  --disable-all-pkgs                            \
  --without-x                                   \
  --without-system-cairo                        \
  --without-system-gmp                          \
  --without-system-graphite2                    \
  --without-system-harfbuzz                     \
  --without-system-libgs                        \
  --without-system-libpaper                     \
  --without-system-mpfr                         \
  --without-system-pixman                       \
  --without-system-poppler                      \
  --without-system-xpdf                         \
  --without-system-icu                          \
  --without-system-fontconfig                   \
  --without-system-freetype2                    \
  --without-system-libpng                       \
  --without-system-zlib                         \
  --with-banner-add=" - BLFS"

make $MAKEFLAGS
make $MAKEFLAGS install
cd texk/web2c
make $MAKEFLAGS xetex
cp xetex $XETEX_EXE
cp $XETEX_EXE $XELATEX_EXE

cd $ROOT
mkdir -p $TEXLIVE
echo selected_scheme scheme-basic > $TEXLIVE/profile.input
echo TEXDIR $TEXLIVE >> $TEXLIVE/profile.input
echo TEXMFLOCAL $TEXLIVE/texmf-local >> $TEXLIVE/profile.input
echo TEXMFSYSVAR $TEXLIVE/texmf-var >> $TEXLIVE/profile.input
echo TEXMFSYSCONFIG $TEXLIVE/texmf-config >> $TEXLIVE/profile.input
echo TEXMFVAR $PWD/home/texmf-var >> $TEXLIVE/profile.input
wget --no-clobber $TEXLIVE_INSTALLER_URL
cd $TEXLIVE
tar xzvf ../install-tl-unx.tar.gz
./install-tl-*/install-tl -profile $TEXLIVE/profile.input
rm -rf bin readme* tlpkg install* *.html texmf-dist/doc texmf-var/web2c

cd $ROOT
export TEXMFDIST=$PWD/texlive/texmf-dist
wget --no-clobber $TEXLIVE_BASE_URL
mkdir -p latex_format
cd latex_format
unzip -o ../base.zip
cd base
$XELATEX_EXE -ini -etex unpack.ins
touch hyphen.cfg
$XELATEX_EXE -ini -etex latex.ltx
                                                                            ```
````

Comment: I'm not really sure why you run the installer at all. If you set up the TDS hierarchy correctly and put the bae files and fonts there, that should be enough.

Comment: To be honest, I was following someone else's tutorials, originally with very little understanding of how Tex or TexLive works internally. Now I think that motivation for running the installer was to make use of some pre-defined profiles ("basic" in my case). If there is a simple way to locally "trim" a full installation without running a net-installer, that would also work! I'd be grateful if you can suggest what that would be. I also don't understand what "base" and "basic" are wrt to installation profile and latex zipball.